# Plotly plot failed to automatically scale inside a modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, plotly.js

I have an issue with Plotly.js and bootstrap.
When inserting a graph within a modal, the plot is not automatically scaled to the modal width even if the plot  width is set to 100%, and the plot layout option autosize set to true.

When opening the modal, the plot is **100px-wide** (instead of 100%) and I have to programatically (or manually) click on the "autoscale" modebar button to correctly display the plot.

You can see this in action with this codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PaGOWv?editors=1010

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div id="myDiv" style="width: 100%;"></div>
 </div>
 <!-- with plotly option: var layout = {autosize: true}; -->
```

I would be very happy if someone has a clue of how to display the plot full-width without having to rescale it after render.

Thanks!
Arnaud

PS: also posted on [github](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/2707)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue happen because plot loading before modal opening.

You may generate plot or update plot layout on loading modal that's working fine.

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
})
```

or

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  Plotly.relayout('myDiv',layout);
})
```

[Example here](https://codepen.io/mdnasirfardoush/pen/zaKWxZ?editors=1010)

Comment: Thanks! What if I have a tabpanel inside this modal? I still have issues going from one tab to the other. See this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YvGJMe)

Comment: OK. Plotly.Plot.resize() seems to be enough.